# Is there a way to extract the data (long) from within the object? Java

Tags: java, oop

Is there a way to extract the distances from within the object and assign it to long variables?
e.g. if user inputs 123 and 234, how would I get those values assigned to new long?

Main method

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestVehicle{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Vehicle car = new Vehicle();


    System.out.print("Input distance 1: ");   
    car.setDistance1(scan.nextLong());
    System.out.print("Input distance 2: ");
    car.setDistance2(scan.nextLong());
```

Class:

```
public class Vehicle {
    private long distance1;
    private long distance2;

public Vehicle(){

}   

public Vehicle(long distance1, long distance2){
this.distance1 = distance1;
this.distance2 = distance2;

public long getDistance1(){
    return distance1;
}
public void setDistance1(long distance1){
    this.distance1 = distance1;
}   
public long getDistance2(){
    return distance2;
}
public void setDistance1(long distance2){
    this.distance2 = distance2;
}
```

Comment: Atleast do some work and then post what's didn't worked.

Comment: You have _getters_, use them.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to extract the distances from within the object and assign it to long variables?

You can use the `getDistance1` and `getDistance2` methods that you have defined on the `Vehicle` class. The point of those methods is to get data out of the class object. Use them like this:

```
long distance1 = car.getDistance1()
```

> I need to print out the longest and shortest distance as well as the average to make the output something like this

Use the technique above to get the values out of the `Vehicle` object. Then perform your mathematical operations in code, and use string concatenation to print the output.